# Encoding problems in python x64

Tags: python, sqlite, encoding

i´m trying to write a little script for writting a sqlite table from an archive list saved in a file. the code so far is this:

```
import os import _sqlite3 import sys

print sys.path[0] mydir = sys.path[0] print (mydir) def listdir(mydir):
    lis=[] 
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mydir):
         for name in files:
             lis.append(os.path.join(root,name))
    return lis
     filename = "list.txt" print ("writting in %s" % filename) file = open(filename, 'w' ) for i in listdir(mydir):
    file.write(i)
    file.write("\n") file.close()

con =
_sqlite3.connect("%s/conection"%mydir) c=con.cursor()

c.execute(''' drop table files ''') c.execute('create table files (name text, other text)') file = open(filename,'r') for line in file :
    a = 1
    for t in [("%s"%line, "%i"%a)]:
        c.execute('insert into files values(?,?)',t)
        a=a+1 c.execute('select * from files') print c.fetchall() con.commit() c.close()
```

when i run i get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\josh\FORGE.py", line 32, in <module>
    c.execute('insert into files values(?,?)',t) ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

i´ve tried with the unicode() built in function but still won´t work, saying that he can´t decode the character 0xed or something.

I know the problem is on the encoding of the list strings, but i can´t find a way to put them right. any ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(zero). please reformat your code

1. after `for line in file:` do something like `line = line.decode('encoding-of-the-file')`, with encoding being something like `utf-8`, or `iso-8859-1` -- **you have to know your input encoding**

   If you don't know the encoding or not care about having a clean decoding, you can guess the most probable encoding and do a `line.decode('uft-8', 'ignore')`, omitting all characters not decodable. Also, you can use `'replace'`, which replaces these chars with the 'Unicode Replacement Character' (\ufffd)
2. use internally and during communication with the database **only** `unicode`objects, e.g. `u'this is unicode'`

(3). Don't use `file` as variable name

also look here: [Best Practices for Python UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933911/best-practices-for-python-unicodedecodeerror/3933973#3933973)

Comment: also, i changed the file name, totally forgot about it being reserved, thanks.