# UnicodeDecodeError in SUDS but only in the .exe generated by py2exe

Tags: python, character-encoding, ascii, py2exe, suds

I have a Python 2.7 script **SendPreord.py** which communicates with web services using **SUDS**. In the script I call a web service method passing some **parameters as strings** (`runJob(par1, par2, par3)`). It works well with western european characters in the strings. I run it in Eclipse with **PyDev**.

Then I generate the **.exe** using **py2exe**. Now it gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SendPreord.py", line 80, in <module>
  File "suds\client.pyc", line 542, in __call__
  File "suds\client.pyc", line 602, in invoke
  File "suds\client.pyc", line 637, in send
  File "suds\transport\https.pyc", line 64, in send
  File "suds\transport\http.pyc", line 77, in send
  File "suds\transport\http.pyc", line 118, in u2open
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 391, in open
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 409, in _open
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 369, in _call_chain
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 1173, in http_open
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 1142, in do_open
  File "httplib.pyc", line 946, in request
  File "httplib.pyc", line 987, in _send_request
  File "httplib.pyc", line 940, in endheaders
  File "httplib.pyc", line 801, in _send_output
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 484: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The code causing the error is:

```
result = ws_client.service.runJob(par1, par2, par3)
```

Investigating, I realized that removing characters like `°èòà` solves the problem... but I can't! I have to preserve the strings I'm passing.

So I tried **decoding** strings before passing them:

```
result = ws_client.service.runJob(par1.decode('latin9'), par2.decode('latin9'), par3.decode('latin9'))
```

Again **all works in .py, but not in .exe**. Maybe PyDev corrects the issue in some way?

---

**ATTACHMENTS**

Setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['src/SendPreord.py'])
```

Interesting extracts from py2exe output log:

```
*** copy dlls ***
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\run.exe -> C:\Users\xxxxxxx\workspace\eclipse\SendPreord\dist\SendPreord.exe
The following modules appear to be missing
['ElementC14N', '_scproxy', 'ntlm']

*** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.

Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

   USER32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
   SHELL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
   WSOCK32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
   ADVAPI32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
   WS2_32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
   KERNEL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

You've been bitten by Python's guessing on encoding conversions. The first part you tried is right: decode first with the (hopefully correct) encoding. Before you send it out, you have to
encode it again, preferrably using something like UTF-8, or else Python tries the "default" encoding (which is in most installations ASCII). [I've written this here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933911/best-practices-for-python-unicodedecodeerror/3933973#3933973)